# Rails gem Invoker : error w Procfile : A line of your INI document could not be parsed to a LineType

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, procfile

I am trying to run a tuts based on a Rails app which is using the invoker gem and a Procfile to start processes ( was app and sidekiq )

I start the rails app from the console  (OS X - bash)  , using

```
bundle exec invoker start Procfile --port 3000
```

and the Profile is the following :

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -v
```

but it raises an error :

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/iniparse-1.1.6/lib/iniparse/parser.rb:65:in `parse_line': A line of your INI document could not be parsed to a LineType: 'web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT'. (IniParse::ParseError)
```

I can start directly the web app with rails server -p 3000
but what could be wrong with the Procfile ?

thanks for enlightments ...

Answer (score 0):

As I am not using Heroku...

I should better use Foreman , I created a Procfile.dev file and used :

```
 foreman start -f Procfile.dev' from the terminal
```

I also  gitignore the Procfile.dev file...